# Create file without listing full path - Java

Tags: java, r.java-file

At the moment I create a file like this:

```
new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Projects\\javaProject\\src\\com\\javaProject\\package\\file.xml");
```

So far listing the whole path is the only way I can get the file to be create inside 'package' otherwise if I just use:

```
new File("file.xml");
```

it just gets created in the source directory and if I use:

```
new File("package\\file.xml");
```

it just throws errors

Comment: How are you executing this? From inside an IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a relative path?

```
new File("com\\javaProject\\package\\file.xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your *Java code* should not be creating files in your package directory.

Eventually, you're going to want to deploy your code, which usually means packaging it in a Jar file. You cannot modify a Jar file from within the code running in the Jar file.

Even if that might be physically possible, *don't do it*. Besides, the code to modify a Jar file is *way* different from your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I did in the same way like **janos** but i think **File.separator** is better then / or \ because someday your program might run on a platform developed in a far-off land, a land of strange things and stranger people, where horses cry and cows operate all the elevators. In this land, people have traditionally used the ":" character as a file separator, and so dutifully the JVM obeys their wishes.